# Why does my <p> element disappear when transform: rotate(45deg)?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my p element to rotate without disappearing...

HTML:

```
<p>Hi there</p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: You need to modify the `transform-origin`.

Comment: It's not disappearing, it is just You can't see it from the screen

Answer (score 1):

It is not disappearing, it's just You can't see it from the screen

See this code snippet:

```css
p {
  background-color: tomato;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Hi there</p>
```

**How to solve it:**

Add a width like this:

```css
p {
        width: 80px;
        background-color: tomato;
        transform: rotate(10deg);
      }
```

```html
<p>Hi there</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is your friend. The default is `center` so with a `p` which is full width by default, a partially filled paragraph may rotate off the page. In the example below I've changed it to `top left` you can adjust that to suite your needs.

```css
p {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Hi there</p>
```